# Trouble eliminating separate query for each child item

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a scenario where I have a Candidate and a Candidate has many Votes.  I want to order the candidates in order of highest votes to lowest.  This query does that:

```
Candidate.joins(:votes).
  select(['candidates.*', 'SUM(votes.score) as total_score']).group('candidates.id, candidates.candidate_id, candidates.user_id, candidates.status, candidates.card_id, candidates.created_at, candidates.updated_at').
  order('candidates.status desc, total_score desc, candidates.created_at asc').where("candidates.riding_id = ? and candidates.status != ?", 124, CandidateStatus::Eligible ).
  having('SUM(votes.score) >= 0')
```

My problem is that I use this to render it:

```
render :json => @candidates.to_json(:include => [:votes])
```

This then causes a query for each candidate to get their votes.  I should be able to do this in one query but no matter how I change it, it still grabs each candidates votes separately.

Answer (score 0):

By the time `#to_json` is called, the votes have to be fetched again, hence each additional query. Using eager-loading, however, it's possible to do this without the additional queries:

```
Candidate.all(:include => :votes).to_json(:include => [:votes])
```

Thus, it can be done with `@candidates` including the eager-loading, such as:

```
@candidates = Candidate.all(:include => :votes)

@candidates.to_json(:include => [:votes])
```

Comment: The docs say that using .joins(:votes) is the proper way to do include now. In any case either does not work - it may work when doing .all but that does not meet the requirements of how i need to sum up the votes and order by those.

Comment: @Codezy: `joins` is not identical to `include`, nor is `include` a replacement in all cases, as far as I understand it (http://railscasts.com/episodes/181-include-vs-joins). `include` loads attributes of the referenced table into memory, and `joins` simply performs a SQL JOIN (this can be examined using the `.to_sql` method on the built query). I think that you probably want `include` in this case - certainly, whilst testing the queries I wrote above, this resulted in the desired behaviour, not resulting in multiple queries. There might well be a neater way, though.

Comment: @Codezy: Ah, it appears the naming changed in Rails 3 to `includes`, and the `.includes` structure is also present. For the specific code you mentioned, you can probably simply change `.joins` to `.includes` (can't test your specific query, as don't have all the models set up), or otherwise include it in the chain. It's important to think carefully about where you're doing this, however, and not use it more often than needed, as it's far less efficient than `joins` for normal queries.